# Invoke exe file from spring boot application

Tags: java, spring

I have somefile.exe in my local and i am currently invoking this exe using process builder by giving absolute path like below

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("C:\\path\\to\\the\\somefile.exe","other commands");
```

I am using spring boot and i dont want to hardcode the absolute path to local, instead i want to make the exe available in project folder.

Where should i put the exe in project folder? I tried placing the exe file in resources folder but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

put the exe file in `src/main/resources` folder. then you can access it from root of the class path.
see [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access) for accessing files in your classpath.